# Make user aware they can’t make an edit before they start editing iOS

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, ios-app

I’ve had this issue several times now.

I go onto a post in the iOS app, put a lot of work into an edit on a site without editing privileges, click submit and then it says I can’t suggest edits to the question.

Either I’m:

- Edit banned
- Another edit is pending

Can we make the user aware they can’t make an edit before they start editing or even making the edit button disappear on such posts?

Comment: Good feature request, but don't have hope on this will be implemented.

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ yeah, I hope the iOS app will resume development soon